# How can I show a counter for a subcategory within an each_with_index loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After searching this for some time, I believe I need to ask this question: 
**How can I show a counter for a subcategory within an each_with_index loop in Rails in a view?**

I thought this would be a common design pattern in Rails, but I've not found an answer...so here goes:

For the record, my environment is: `ruby 2.0.0p353, rails Rails 4.1.4.`

I have two models, **Titles and Categories**. There is a 1-M relationship from Categories to Titles (these are for a DVD Catalog app):

**the Category model:**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :titles
 end
```

**the Title model:**

```
class Title < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category  
end
```

**the relevant schema:**

```
  create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "category_name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "titles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "year_published"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end
```

And here is the **view** I wish to modify:

```
 <tbody>
    <% @titles.each_with_index do |title, index| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= index %></td>
        <td><%= title.title %></td>
        <td><%= title.year_published %></td>
        <td><%= title.category.try(:category_name) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', title %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_title_path(title) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', title, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

When the **index.html** page is displayed for Titles, I would to include in my view, which displays Titles sorted within Categories, both an overall counter for Titles, but also a sub counter for the record entry within its Category, and have that counter reset to zero with each new Category.

Here is what my **Titles controller** contains to retrieve Titles, and sort Titles within Category:

```
@titles = Title.includes(:category).order("categories.category_name asc, title")
```

which, when I call up the titles index.html page, looks like (sorry for bad formatting; fields showns are:

```
index, title_name, year_published, category, show/edit/destroy): 

    0   Cliffhanger 1993    Action  Show    Edit    Destroy
    1   Ironman I   2008    Action  Show    Edit    Destroy
    2   K2  1991    Action  Show    Edit    Destroy
    3   Bulworth    1998    Comedy  Show    Edit    Destroy
    4   Coming To America   1988    Comedy  Show    Edit    Destroy
    5   Forgetting Sarah Marshall   2008    Comedy  Show    Edit    Destroy
    6   My Blue Heaven  1990    Comedy  Show    Edit    Destroy
    7   A Lot Like Love 2005    Comedy/Romantic Show    Edit    Destroy
    8   Once    2006    Comedy/Romantic Show    Edit    Destroy
    9   Strictly Sexual 2008    Comedy/Romantic Show    Edit    Destroy
    10  The Other Side of the Mirror        Comedy/Romantic Show    Edit    Destroy
    11  Women On Top    2000    Comedy/Romantic Show    Edit    Destroy
    12  YFP 2007    Comedy/Romantic Show    Edit    Destroy
    13  A Crude Awakening   2006    Documentary Show    Edit    Destroy
...
```

How can I add a second index counter, that will show the index *within* a Category? (This will actually be very helpful for the physical storing of the DVDs within the catalog.)

Many TIA, 
--rixter

Comment: what have you got so far? (ie the loop that has the `each_with_index`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to iterate over the titles? Why not iterate over the categories and within each category iterate over the relevant titles?

Then you get the category index for free and it is very easy to add an outer counter for the total index.

edit:
You can add an outer index like this.

```
<tbody>
  <% outer_index = 0 %>
  <% @categories.each_with_index do |cat, cat_index| %>
    <% cat.titles.each do |title| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= outer_index %></td>
        <td><%= cat_index %></td>
        <td><%= title.title %></td>
        <td><%= title.year_published %></td>
        <td><%= title.category.try(:category_name) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', title %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_title_path(title) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', title, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
      <% outer_index++ %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: A good idea, but the reason to iterate over titles is because it is more helpful when sorting a pile of unsorted DVD's, and all I have it the title on the disk. But I do not see how "it is very easy to add an outer counter"? That's why I asked the question in the first place....

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view helper for Titles that creates a category counter:

```
# app/helpers/title_helper.rb
module TitleHelper
  def category_index(title)
    @category_counter ||= []
    @category_counter[title.category_id] ||= -1
    @category_counter[title.category_id] += 1
  end
end
```

This adds a rolling counter of Titles for each Category. Then in `index.html.erb`

```
<% @titles.each_with_index do |title, index| %>
  ...
  <td><%= category_index(title) %></td>
  ...
<% end %>
```

The limitation of this is that all Titles need to be iterated begining from the first Title. This is obviously breaks (like all Ruby `index` solutions) if anything like pagination comes into play or if the order of Titles in index.html.erb differs from how Titles are ordered within a Category.

Comment: Thanks Pete; I will try this approach, which looks like it should work..within the limitations you mention. (Pagination will come later in this learning exercise...)

Comment: I just reused your code -- and it works great. Thanks for helping me understand helpers a bit more....

Comment: Happy to help :) If it works as planned, could you mark your question as answered?